# Pushing texture information to OpenGLES for iPad - Implications?

Tags: ipad, opengl-es, textures

We have a project that is up and coming that will require us to push texture image information to a the EAGLView of an iPad app.  Being green to OpenGL in general, are there implications to having a surface wait for texture information?  What will OpenGL do while it's waiting for the image data?  Does OpenGL require constant updates to it's textures, or will it retain the data until we update the texture again? We're not going to be having a loop or anything in the view, but more like an observer pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a texture, you hand it off to the GPU — so a copy is made, in memory you don't have direct access to. It's then available to be drawn with as many times as you want. So there's no need for constant updates.

OpenGL won't do anything else while waiting for the image data, it's a synchronous API. The call to upload the data will take as long as it takes, the texture object will have no graphic associated with it beforehand and will have whatever you uploaded associated with it afterwards.

In the general case, OpenGL objects, including texture objects, belong to a specific context and contexts belong to a specific thread. However, iOS implements [share groups](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/OpenGLES/Reference/EAGLSharegroup_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLSharegroup.html), which allow you to put several contexts into a share group, allowing objects to be shared between them subject to you having to be a tiny bit careful about synchronisation.

iOS provides a specific subclass of CALayer, [CAEAGLLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CAEAGLLayer_Class/CAEGLLayer/CAEGLLayer.html), that you can use to draw to from OpenGL. It's up to you when you draw and how often. So your approach is the more native one, if anything. A lot of the samples wrap

Obviously try the simplest approach of 'everything on the main thread' first. If you're not doing all that much then it'll likely be fast enough and save you code maintenance.  However, uploading can cost more than you expect, since the OpenGL way around of working is that you specify the data and the format it's in, leaving OpenGL to rearrange it as necessary for the particular GPU you're on. We're talking amounts of the 0.3 of a second variety rather than 30 seconds, but enough that there'll be an obvious pause if the user taps a button or tries to move a slider at the same time.

So if keeping the main thread responsive proves an issue, I'd imagine that you'd want to hop onto a background thread, create a new context within the same share group as the one on the main thread, upload, then hop back to do the actual drawing. In which case it'll remain up to you how you communicate to the user that data has been received and is being processed as distinct from no data having been received yet, if the gap is large enough to justify doing so.

Comment: Yea, we're tackling this in the main thread at first.  I like your post, it's very informative.  Thanks for the information :)